# Como transpor linhas em colunas (e vice-versa) e salvar em um novo banco de dados?

Tags: r

Meu banco de dados tem 10 casos e 6 variáveis. Quero transpor os casos em coluna e salvar essa transposição em um banco de dados.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize a função `t`:

```
dados <- head(cars)
dados
  speed dist
1     4    2
2     4   10
3     7    4
4     7   22
5     8   16
6     9   10
t(dados)
      1  2 3  4  5  6
speed 4  4 7  7  8  9
dist  2 10 4 22 16 10
```

O `R` possui diversas maneiras de salvar dados em arquivos. A minha preferida é utilizando a função `write.csv`:

```
write.csv(t(dados), file="dados.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Desta forma, o arquivo `dados.csv` será criado e vai poder ser importado em qualquer outro programa que leia dados separados por vírgula, como o Excel, por exemplo.